# How to execute scala project from sbt pack/bin folder on linux machine

Tags: linux, scala, sbt, executable

I am new to scala. I have configured sbt pack in scala project and executed the command `sbt pack`. It creates new folder '/target/pack' and has lib and bin folder. bin folder contains two file. one is batch file. I have double clicked that file and it executes the project from command prompt.

Question: how to run in liunx machine? Does this bin folder is created to run the project with simple click?

build.sbt

```
enablePlugins(PackPlugin)
name := "FileReadAWS"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.4"
```

plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-pack" % "0.13")
```

the bellow file has been created after i execute 'sbt pack' from command prompt

```
\target\pack\bin\file-reader Type is 'File'
\target\pack\bin\file-reader Type is 'Windows-Batch file' It execute the program when double clicked
\target\pack\lib  This folder contains project jar and dependency jar as well
```

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The JAR file created with **sbt package** command is a normal Java JAR file.
You can also execute the main method in the JAR file with the Scala interpreter: i.e.

> $ scala target/scala-2.10/.jar

[Referral link](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-compile-run-package-scala-project/)

Comment: This question is about the sbt-pack plugin:
https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack